# Prevent duplicates MD5 when upload images

Tags: php, mysql

I'm uploading pictures with generated md5 hash for each but sometime happens duplicates.

```
  $rand = rand(0,10000);
  $md5  = md5($rand);
```

Comment: you are naming your images as the md5 value ?

Comment: Why don't you use `sha1_file` to generate the SHA1 hash of the file? Well, if someone uploads the same file, then you'll have only one file, but you can just check if there are more than one database entry for that file and only delete the file if there is a single entry (which you are going to delete anyway).

Comment: Other than that you could just use `md5(microtime(true))`

Comment: Of course there are duplicates.  There are way more possible images than possible md5 values.  Learn about something called the pigeon-hole principle.

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois I'm not using SHA1 because I don't know for that.
If I increase value of $rand = rand(0,10000000000); ?

Comment: `I don't know for that` what is that supposed to mean? Using the SHA1 hash of a file prevents duplicate images on your server, so you save space. You just need to do some checks before deleting the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it is normal that md5 is making a duplicate in your case if you are choosing a random value betweeen `0,10000` what if the random value was twice `500` then your md5 will has the 2 values to same hash.

instead I would suggest you doing this :

```
  $uniqTime = microtime(); //microtime is the time unix in milliseconds that is the most unique number you can reach, you can use it alone or rehash it, even though I find hashing it to be useless
  $md5  = md5($uniqTime); // you can use the $uniqTime alone without rehashing it
```

Comment: Ok I've updated my code, it looks like no duplicates happened!
Thanks!

Comment: Can it work for multiple uploads at same time for e.g if I upload 30pictures?

Comment: Yes because you are dealing with Microseconds you have a chance of one per 10^12 to have 2 occurrences of the same number which is extremely rare and that case would occur only in multi threading languages like Java but never php which is a single-threaded one

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this for truly unique hash names (even in the unlikely event that 2 users upload files at the same exact microsecond):

```
  $hash = sha1(mt_rand(0,9999999999).time());
```

Edit: By "truly unique", I mean it's very unlikely that you will get collisions with this for your usage, unless we are talking about millions of images... then it could happen.

Comment: I wouldn't call this truly unique. Just highly unlikely that a collision will happen.

Comment: well, no need to downvote. I added explanation that collisions can occur, however I was thinking that for the op needs this will most probably be 100% unique.

Comment: Thanks I've learn something new!
I'll try too!
I don't have huge uploads this will work fine :)

Comment: You can read some explanation about md5 vs sha1 here (if interested): http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19705/is-sha1-better-than-md5-only-because-it-generates-a-hash-of-160-bits and here: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18612/how-is-sha1-different-from-md5

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Php's [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function for names?

```
<?php
$name = uniqid();
```